# Accessing Content provider android studio

Tags: java, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

i wanna acessing content provider to save and store data from web service, so when the user open the apps the data still saved.
( i just copied and manipulated script from sunshine cause i didnt know content provider work :( )

this is my script for [content provider](https://gist.github.com/cahyowhy/f83d39751e8ea7cdc7822607716e4aa5)

and this is for [content adapter](https://gist.github.com/cahyowhy/52d9a40e0e560665d194a8d79db03ca8)

how to acessing content provider from content adapter??
thankss

Answer (score 1):

Google has a piece on this pattern: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html